# Castle Windsor Typed Factory Close Open Generic

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I'm not sure if this is possible, but we want to do the following

We have Processors that processes a type of Message. Each Message has a MessageOrigin. The Processor need diffrent Mappers based on the MessageOrigin. The Processor is not interested in the MessageOrigin.

This gives us the following code (full Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/LodewijkSioen/9807993))

```
public class ConcreteMessageProcessor<TMessageOrigin> 
    : IProcessor<ConcreteMessage, TMessageOrigin>
{
    public ConcreteMessageProcessor(IMapper<TMessageOrigin> mapper){}
}
```

We also have a TypedFactory to create the processor:

```
public interface IProcessorFactory
{
    IProcessor[] GetAllProcessorsForMessage(Message message, 
        IMessageOrigin origin);
}
```

Combined with a Selector:

```
public class ProcessorSelector : DefaultTypedFactoryComponentSelector
{
    protected override Type GetComponentType(MethodInfo method, 
        object[] arguments)
    {
        return typeof(IProcessor<,>).MakeGenericType(arguments[0].GetType(),
            arguments[1].GetType()).MakeArrayType();
    }
}
```

However, when we call the `IProcessorFactory`, we never get a processor. I guess that this is because the TMessageOrigin is still open when the type is registered in the container. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

From what i see in your gist you don't have an implementation of a `ProcessorImp` that specifies both its generic types. That's certainly the reason why the factory cannot resolve `IProcessor`: you're trying to resolve the service `IProcessor<MessageImpl, MessageOriginImp>` but the component that you have registered implements

```
IProcessor<Message, TMessageOrigin>
where TMessageOrigin : IMessageOrigin
```

Perhaps you should rethink the way you are trying to register/resolve your services; your `MessageOriginImpl` could have an interface `IIsOriginFor<MessageImpl>` and the factory would resolve these based on the type of `MessageImpl`

Comment: I know there is no Processor with the exact generic footprint registered, but I wondered if Castle could close that last open generic for me using the arguments in the Selector.

Comment: I don't think that Castle can close this pending generic value, and that you must resolve it explicitly in your factory. That is why i was suggesting rethinking the way you register/resolve the services. If you only ever have one MessageOrigin for a Message, then you don't need the IProcessor to know about the MessageOrigin, since it could be resolved from the Message. And if there are many MessageOrigin per Message, then you must choose how the system must resolve and handle them

Comment: We have multiple origins per message. We have re-thought the system, but I think there could be a way to close the generic in Castle, somehow involving `IGenericImplementationMatchingStrategy`

Comment: @Lodewijk I really looked at the `IGenericImplementationMatchingStrategy` but i couldn't find a case where the second type is collapsed automatically. Even the example here uses a direct match from implementation to automaticresolution: http://kozmic.net/2013/07/24/on-castle-windsor-and-open-generic-component-arity/